# Tsc works fine, gulp build fails including node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, tsc

I'm new to typescript and gulp and got a working project, where tsc is working fine(with tsconfig.js) but gulp build wasn't configured. I'm trying with this aproach:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var tsc = require('gulp-typescript');
...
var tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");
gulp.task('build', function () {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./output"));
});
```

and get bunch of TS2307 errors:

```
... : error TS2307: Cannot find module 'csvtojson'.
... : error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.
```

I'm wondering how to configure the gulp to work exacly as tsc does? I include the modules this way:

```
import * as csvtojson from "csvtojson";
import * as moment from "moment";
```

Any ideas?